# iOS: View Controller Instance does not deallocated if I pass it to dispatch_async block

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, dealloc, dispatch-async

```
UIViewController* vc = [[NSClassFromString(record.anObject) alloc] initWithNibName:record.anObject bundle:nil];

1) [myNavigationController navigateToViewController:vc animated:NO];

2) dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
   @autorelesepool
   {
       [myNavigationController navigateToViewController:vc animated:NO];         
   }
});
```

Please check the code 1 and 2. If I use 1 then view controller `vc` gets deallocated when pop from navigation stack and If I use 2 then my view controller does not deallocated when it is pop from naviagation stack.

I am using `ARC`. Can any body tell me how can I free vc's memory for 2nd implementation? I tried temp variable of `__block` type and set it to `nil` at the end of disaptch_async block but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
__weak UIViewController *weakVC = vc;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
   [myNavigationController pushViewController:weakVC animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: @Oleg is right, anything that goes to dispatcher has to be weakly instantiated

Comment: Since you're only using the weak variable once it's okay, but any weakly captured variable used more than once in a block should be captured strongly first, otherwise it may become nil while your code expects to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The only differences between the two are:

1. one performs the action synchronously while the other one does it asynchronously
2. `myNavigationController` (if it's a local variable) and `vc` is retained until the asynchronous operation executes

Because `vc` is referenced by the block, it won't be deallocated before the asynchronous operation executes. If there are no further strong references to that object at that point, it will be deallocated after the asynchronous operation executes.